# Why set a socket to blocking after setting SO_LINGER values?

Tags: linux, sockets, unix, solaris

I'm looking at some proprietary legacy code that is setting a non blocking socket to blocking after doing the following.

```
    lbuf.l_onoff = 1;
    lbuf.l_linger = 0;
    e = setsockopt(s->s_fd, SOL_SOCKET,
            SO_LINGER, (optvalp)&lbuf, sizeof(lbuf));
```

Any thoughts why this might be needed either now or in the past ?

Code has supported Windows, Unixware, and Solaris in the past. Currently running on CentOs linux.

Comment: What functions are being called to flush the socket?

Comment: I'm also at a loss as to what you mean by "flushing the socket".  The concept of "flushing a socket" isn't generally implemented.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets

Comment: @JeremyFriesner . I edited the question to show the actual code.